# Sas9 Replace special characters with underscores

Tags: special-characters, sas

In Sas9, how can I replace all the , \ / or spaces, and other special characters of my choosing with underscores?  A solution either in a datastep or in macro functions would do the trick, I'm just looking for a method to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the Perl regular expression functionality built into SAS.

```
data tmp;
 set tmp;
 var1 = prxchange('s/[,\/\\]/_/', -1, var);
run;
```

or something similar.

Answer (score 2):

The translate function might be what you're looking for

```
field2 = translate(trim(field_name),'_______',' ,.\/()')
```

Make sure to have as many underscores as you have special characters.  Also, because you're translating spaces, you have to use the trim function or else you'll get a bunch of underscores after the name.